# React Element won't handle onMouseEnter

Tags: reactjs, react-native, event-handling

Hello I am working on a Chess Web Application with React.

I am trying to update the render with a handle method whenever a mouse enters or leaves one of my squares. I already have this working for when I click on a square.

When I add onMouseEnter to the Square Element of its render method, nothing happens. I was able to notice however that if I added onMouseEnter to the button element contained within the square, I can make something happen.

However I would like to have the Board class be able to handle these so it can update the board based upon which square it is. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my code within the render square method:

```
return (
            <Square
                src={pieceStr}
                key={pieceStr}
                onMouseEnter = {() => console.log("I dont work")}//this.handleHover(x, y)}
                onClick={() => this.handleClick(x, y)}
                className={classes}
            />
        );
```

And here is my code for the Square Class' render method:

```
return (
        <button
            onDragOver={(e) => this.onDragOver(e)}
            onMouseOver={() => console.log("I work")}
            className={this.props.className}
            onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}
        >
            {img}
        </button>
    );
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use onMouseEnter event on a real dom element. just pass it in a prop.

```
<button onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}{...rest}>{img}</button>
```

Comment: Thank You!!! This works!

Passing Down
onMouseOver={() => this.handleHover(x,y)}

In the Child
onMouseOver={this.props.onMouseOver}